# SSRS row groups are duplicated

Tags: ssrs-2008

The following query does an inventory valuation:

```
select M.UserFld3, M.ItemID, D.ShortDesc, W.QtyOnHand, V.StdUnitCost, (W.QtyOnHand * V.StdUnitCost) as 'TotalValue'
from timItem M
inner join timInventory V on M.ItemKey = V.ItemKey
inner join timItemDescription D on V.ItemKey = D.ItemKey
inner join timWhseBinInvt W on D.ItemKey = W.ItemKey
where 
-- Conditions
order by M.UserFld3, M.ItemID
```

The query returns 2861 rows in about a dozen categories: Hardware, Hoses, Fittings, Brackets, Electrical, etc. I display the results in a table with collapsible sections for each category. My problem is that some of these categories are duplicated, so I have two expandable categories for Brackets. (I would post an image, but I need 10 reputation points.) The items in these two categories are correct and not duplicated. I want only each category listed once. How do I do that? I don't think this is a problem with the SQL, and I can't find any problems with the report.

Comment: Sounds like a grouping issue in the table. If you're grouping on ItemID, make sure "Brackets" can only have 1 ItemID. Otherwise, add another field with the category name that you can group on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that some categories included trailing blanks, resulting in categories such as 'Hoses' and 'Hoses '. And easy fix by eliminating trailing blanks in the table.